# Failed to use reduce with partial in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have following function which should return the answer of `update-in` function:

```
(defn abc
  [a fruit-1 fruit-2]
  (update-in a ["apples" (xyz fruit-1)]
             add-apple
             fruit-1
             fruit-2))
```

And I am using reduce with partial (since the function has 3 parameters) to call that function:

```
(let [fruits (get-fruits config)]
    (let [the-basket (reduce (partial abc empty-map) (first fruits) (second fruits))]
      (if (empty? (the-basket "apples"))
          (throw (ex-info "Couldn't find" {}))
          the-basket)))
```

Where `fruits` contains two elements in it.

However, it is not even calling the "`abc`" function (via debug) and `the-basket` gets exact same value with `(first fruits)` directly.

So apparently, I am not using this reduce & partial part: `(reduce (partial abc empty-map) (first fruits) (second fruits))`

Is it correct way to call a function with 3 parameters via reduce; or is it some other (better) way to do that?

Comment: For better help, provide a complete executable example. To troubleshoot on your own, if you have a question about partial, you may replace it with `#(abc empty-map %)` and see what happens. You could also put a `(println ...)` into function abc to check your expectations of your debugger.

Comment: Thanks @BipedPhill, actually fruits is getting from db so I didn't include that part. And the "println" can give idea about the function is calling or not and it is not calling; which is the problem. In other words, I have a "abc" function which takes 3 parameters. And I need to use reduce on that. So, my approach (`(reduce (partial abc empty-map) (first fruits) (second fruits))`) is correct or not?

Comment: I think you are expecting reduce to "zip" your two fruits sequences.  
This is not the case - the three argument reduce expects a reducing     
function, an initial value, and the sequences to iterate over. I think you should basically: transpose the result of `get-fruits` and destructure in abc.  E.g. `defn abc [a [f1 f2]] ...` and later `(reduce abc empty-map (transpose fruits))`

Comment: The correctness of your approach depends on the context. You should tell us what are you trying to achieve, what input data look like and what result you want to return. If you have exact instructions (e.g. from the teacher), you should also add them.  It's hard to debug something if we don't know what functions like `get-fruits`, `xyz` or `add-apple` do.

Answer (score 0):

This usage of `reduce` is incorrect, for a few reasons:

The usage of `(partial abc empty-map)` means the resulting function takes two arguments, but the first argument, `a`, is *always* `empty-map`. It doesn't update it in place. The way `reduce` works as well will produce incorrect values for you here.

In your sample code it will call the partial function with the first fruit and the result of calling `first` on the second fruit, which likely gives you an incorrect value, because the three-argument form of `reduce` expects the second argument to be an initial value and the third argument to be a sequence.

In this case where you know that `fruits` will have only two values, you are most likely looking for `apply`, as in the following:

```clj
(apply abc empty-map fruits)
```

This will produce a call to `abc` with `empty-map` as the first argument, and each element of `fruits` to be additional arguments to `abc`, and since you know there are exactly two elements in this sequence, it should produce a correct call.